# how to wait for task.run

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, async-await, task-parallel-library

I am writing a windows store app and needs some help on `Task.Run` method. I am calling service to retrieve data from a service; because I want to cancel the task when internet is disconnected I am passing CancellationToken

```
await Task.Run(async () => await Download1(), cts.Token);
```

There is another download method which should run after this above task is finished so I am using await. Both the tasks write to same files so I want to make sure that they do not run in parallel.

```
await Task.Run(async () => await Download2(), cts.Token);
```

The issue is that above task 2 starts without task 1 is finished and so both task run in parallel. What I am doing wrong? Please advise.

Download1 looks like this:-

```
 public async Task Download1()
        {
         await   Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                         async () =>
                         {
                             Status = "Downloading!";
                             var ListSetupTasks = new List<SetupView>();
                             foreach (var setup in AllSetupTasks.Setup)
                             {
                                 ListSetupTasks.Add(new SetupViewModel(setup));
                             }

                             IEnumerable<Task> downloadTasksQuery = from setup in ListSetupTasks where setup.TaskType == TaskType.Web select _masterlistrepository.GetTask(setup, false, datetime, branch);
                             Task[] downloadTasks = downloadTasksQuery.ToArray();
                             await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasks);

                             IEnumerable<Task> FinalTasksQuery = from setup in ListSetupTasks where setup.TaskType == TaskType.Web select _masterlistrepository.GetTask(setup, false);
                             foreach (var task in FinalTasksQuery)
                             {
                                 await task;
                             }
                         });

        }
```

The CancellationToken is used like this:-

```
async void NetworkChanged(object sender, NetworkConnectionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Value == false && LoadingData == true)
            {

             await   Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                            async () =>
                            {
                                await _alertmessageservice.ShowAsync("", "Network error. Please retry!");
                                cts.Cancel();
                            });

            }
        }
```

Comment: How does `Download1` and `Download2` look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use the [`CoreDispatcher.RunAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync.aspx) which accepts a [`DispatchedHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.dispatchedhandler.aspx). `DispatchedHandler` has this signature:

```
public delegate void DispatchedHandler()
```

So when you pass in an `async` lambda it will end up being `async void`. That makes it impossible to `await` as there's no task being returned. This means that everything after an `await` in your lambdas will run on a different thread concurrently.

You shouldn't be passing an `async` delegate to that method.

---

As a side note, passing a `CancellationToken` doesn't enable to automatically stop the operation. It can only stop the operation before it starts or if you're observing the token somewhere inside the operation.

So, to actually use the `CancellationToken` `Download` should accept use it which makes the `Task.Run` redundant:

```
await Download1Async(cts.Token);
```

Comment: Perfect..makes sense. I will change the code accordingly. I updated my code above; do you think that the cancellationtoken use is incorrect? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Matt's comment on that is pretty complete.

Answer (score 5):

Can you just call them sequentially?

```
await Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await Download1();
    await Download2();
});
```

You might not even need `Task.Run`, unless you are calling from a UI thread.  If you're already on a background thread, then try just:

```
await Download1();
await Download2();
```

Of course, your cancellation token should probably be passed into the download function either way.

Comment: I will try that. I added the event where I cancel the task; is it incorrect? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You still need to pass the CT into the download function, and check `IsCancellationRequested`, and/or pass it into the various functions you are calling.